# R correlation coefficient of columns for each row of matrix

Tags: r

trying to get the correlation coeffizient  between the columns of each row of the matrix. I am reall new to R and it is a real beginner thing here. One of the first tasks I have to do for class.

Matrix:

```
 A2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   -2
[2,]    8   -3
[3,]    6    1
[4,]    2    2
[5,]   -1    1
```

I tried to use `cor(A)` since I read it will automatically calculate the correlation coeffizient for columns of each row, but it gives me the following result:

```
cor(A2)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.6338878
[2,] -0.6338878  1.0000000
```

when using cor(t(A2))

```
cor(t(A2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1   NA   -1
[2,]    1    1    1   NA   -1
[3,]    1    1    1   NA   -1
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    1   NA
[5,]   -1   -1   -1   NA    1
```

But I expected it to have 5 rows, one column with the result in it.

Comment: Are you looking for `cor(t(A2))`. I am not sure what you mean by "correlation coefficients between the columns of each row of the matrix"

Comment: Sorry missed that part. The first column represents all X values and the second all Y values. Now my task is to calculate the correlation coeffizient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to use the `cor()` function. If you want to calculate the correlation between two columns in a matrix, then you can provide two arguments like this:

```
> cor(A2[,1], A2[,2])
[1] -0.6338878
```

If you input a single matrix as an argument, then it will return a correlation matrix.

```
> cor(A2)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.6338878
[2,] -0.6338878  1.0000000
```

In this case, position `[1,1]` is the correlation  between the `A2[,1]` and `A2[,1]` (which is exactly 1). In the position `[1,2]`, you can find the correlation between `A2[,1]` and `A2[,2]`.  The correlation matrix is symmetric, and the diagnonal is always 1, because the correlation of a vector with itself is 1.